# How to use "NoTransition" in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

This first code works as a slide transition however, I am trying to implement the "NoTransition" option but I can't find anything on google nor does the documentation shows how to code it.

```
def option_2(self):
    self.manager.current = "go_to_element_2_screen"
    self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
def option_2(self):
    self.manager.current = "go_to_element_2_screen"
    self.manager.transition = NoTransition
```

How can I implement the "NoTransition" option in kivymd?

Comment: Try just adding `()`, like this: `self.manager.transition = NoTransition()`, but do it before you change the current screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per John Anderson's advice above, my code was missing a `()` after `NoTransition`. The following works:

```
def option_2(self):
    self.manager.transition = NoTransition()
    self.manager.current = "go_to_element_2_screen"
```